# Why is it not possible to catch HTTP error in Angular when server is down?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient, angular-http

There is a REST-service in my Angular 9 to handle all HTTP requests. When I shutdown the REST server there are errors in the `console.log()` but I'm unable to catch them in the service:

```
    return this.http.post<any[]>(this.path, data, header).pipe(
        catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log("---", err);

            return of(null);
        })
    );
```

console output is always:

```
    zone-evergreen.js:2845 HEAD https://SERVER/ net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

Why does this happen and why is `catchError` being ignorred?

Comment: if you dont catch it in the catchError() that very weird.
the errors should be display to you in the catchError() method of rxjs.

Comment: @Talg123 this is exactly my problem, because I don't understand why this happen

Comment: That is probably because the request did not even go through and never came back i.e. the processing was stopped then and there. Have you tried catching the error in a `HttpInterceptor`?

Comment: How Manish said, your request is stopped by httpinterceptor

Answer (score 0):

You will get errors in catchError for errors related to http calls. In this case your call even didn't reach any server. For catching these type for errors you can setup a global error handler by implementing ErrorHandler interface. Please refer to link below for doing that :-

https://medium.com/@aakashgarg19/advanced-exception-handling-with-power-of-dependency-injection-in-angular-93cd7422f051